# How can I increment a custom ID field using a while loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to generate an ID where the format is 000H-Y where the numbers go from 000 to 019. My code is only generating from 010H-Y to 019H-Y. Is there a formatting problem or an error with my while loop?

```
if exists(select * from sysobjects where name = 'Bikes')
    drop table Bikes
go

create table Bikes
(
    BikeID nchar(6) not null,
        constraint pk_Bikes_BikeID primary key(BikeID),
        constraint chk_Bikes_BikeID check(BikeID like ('0[0-19][HYS]-[AP]')),
    StableDate date not null
        default getdate()
)
go

if exists(select * from sysobjects where name = 'PopulateBikes')
    drop procedure PopulateBikes
go

create procedure PopulateBikes
@outcome as nvarchar(12) output
as
declare @min as int = 0, 
@max as int = 19
    if @@ERROR <> 0
        return -1
    while(@min < @max)
    begin
        set @min+=1
        insert into Bikes(BikeID)
        values ('0'+ cast(@min as nvarchar(2))+ 'H-A')
        
    end
go

declare @retVal as int = 0
exec @retVal = PopulateBikes 'SPName:OK'
if @retVal = -1
    print 'Error encountered!'
go

select * from Bikes go
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 1 N
  UNION ALL
  SELECT N + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE N <= 18
)

SELECT CAST(N AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'H-Y'
       -- or SELECT '0' + CAST(N AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'H-Y'
FROM CTE;
```

There is no need to use `WHILE` loop, and it kill performance.

Also your `CHECK` constraint is wron, it should be like

```
CONSTRAINT CH_Bikes_BikeID CHECK(BikeID LIKE '0[0-9]H-Y' OR BikeID LIKE '0[0-9][0-9]H-Y')
```

So, here is your table and the query to populate it

```
CREATE TABLE Bikes
(
  BikeID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  StableDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GetDate(),
  CONSTRAINT CH_Bikes_BikeID CHECK(BikeID LIKE '0[0-9]H-Y' OR BikeID LIKE '0[0-9][0-9]H-Y'),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Bikes_BikeID PRIMARY KEY (BikeID)
);

WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 1 N
  UNION ALL
  SELECT N + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE N <= 18
)

INSERT INTO Bikes (BikeID)
SELECT '0' + CAST(N AS VARCHAR(10)) + 'H-Y'
FROM CTE;

SELECT *
FROM Bikes
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEN(BikeID) = 5
          THEN 0
          ELSE 1
          END;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=efbc0f60bc1fac660303cdae706b7b74)**

---

*UPDATE*

From the code you provide to create the table I assume you are wrong, cause I think those chars are the possible values, so you can create your table as

```
CREATE TABLE Bikes
(
  BikeID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  StableDate DATE NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Bikes_StableDate DEFAULT GetDate(),
  CONSTRAINT PK_Bikes_BikeID PRIMARY KEY (BikeID),
  CONSTRAINT CH_Bikes_BikeID 
  CHECK(BikeID LIKE '0[0-9][H,Y,S]-[A,P]' OR BikeID LIKE '0[0-9][0-9][H,Y,S]-[A,P]')
);
```

And here is an example of inserting the data to it

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 1 N
  UNION ALL
  SELECT N + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE N <= 18
)

INSERT INTO Bikes (BikeID)
SELECT '0' + CAST(N AS VARCHAR(10)) + 
       CASE WHEN N % 3 = 1
            THEN 'H-A'
            ELSE 'Y-P'
            END
FROM CTE
ORDER BY N;

SELECT *
FROM Bikes
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEN(BikeID) = 5
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
              END;
```

The line `CHECK(BikeID LIKE '0[0-9][H,Y,S]-[A,P]' OR BikeID LIKE '0[0-9][0-9][H,Y,S]-[A,P]')` check the possible values, eg:

- `H-A` allowed
- `Y-P` allowed
- `S-P` allowed
- `K-A` not allowed
- `AB-AP` not allowed

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Consider how you generate values for `BikeID`.

With this line:

```
select ('0'+ cast(@min as nvarchar(2))+ 'H-Y')
```

you will generate values from `01H-Y` to `019H-Y`.

Try with this:

```
select RIGHT('000'+ cast(@min as nvarchar(2)), 3) + 'H-Y'
```

Also you need to change your check constraint to:

```
constraint chk_Bikes_BikeID check(BikeID LIKE '0[0-9][0-9][HYS]-[AYP]')
```